# Detecting duplicated table rows with Xcode UI testing

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to catch a case of records being listed twice in a tableview shortly after app launch. I believe this is a bug in one of my `UIViewController` subclasses. The string value can be found by `XCUIApplication().tables.staticTexts["Example string"]`, and I've chosen the value that I expect to appear in the first row, meaning that if the row is duplicated, it will be visible along with its original (rather than offscreen and not yet in a cell instance). But I'm apparently not able to iterate over the static texts like this:

```
var nameCounter = 0
for aStaticText in XCUIApplication().tables.staticTexts.element {
    aName = aStaticText.label
    if ("Example string" == aName) {
        nameCounter += 1
    }
}
```

My `for...in` statement generates an error: Type 'XCUIElement' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'.

Is there another way I could perform this test? If I could insert the staticTexts strings into an array or set, that would do the trick. Or is there another way to find duplicated values in table rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements can be enumerated with `allElementsBoundByIndex`:

```
for aStaticText in XCUIApplication().tables.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex {
// ...
}
```